# Requirement of streaming server for playing video in html

Tags: video-streaming, red5

I have some .mp4 and files which I want to view through my web application.
The application has been built using spring2.5 and struts2 
There is a jsp page which has links to the .mp4 files. As soon as a link is clicked, a ajax call is going to fetch the path of the .mp4 file and embed it in the jsp page, which then starts playing the same.

My questions  are
1) Whether I need a streaming server like Red5 to play the video files or not ?
2) What might be the advantages or disadvantages of using or not using a streaming server in the above case?
3) Will the format of files like .flv, .avi, .mp4 affect the decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to have 50 reputation to comment but none to answer ??

We use Wowza streaming server. I am not familar with red5.

FFmpeg also streams.  In your case wowza would be better but ffmpeg is great for debugging stufff.  With wowza you have test players and the urls get built for you - makes life a little easier.

If you post flv, avi, mp4, etc on a web server and link to it, when the browser fetches that link webserver (not streaming server) /client down load the entire file - then will play.  This is true also of mp3 files (so you can post it, fetch it and see what happens, because they are typically smaller files - the download time is less).

The streaming server download 'chuncks' of the file plays etc.

With both ffmpeg and wowza the type of file you start with is not terrible important (flv, mp4, avi, etc) All work.

A) ffmpeg to stream simple video - open stream with vlc player - if working move on to next.
B) read Wowza (or other streaming server) to do quality streaming.

Comment: Yes, because someone with low rep could flood the comment section, but can post only one answer